# How do I remove my IntelliJ license in 2019.3?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have JetBrains IntelliJ installed, how do I remove the license settings? I can find the license details in `Help > Register...` menu but that does not allow me to remove license settings or to enter invalid data like a nonexisting license server.

Use case: I have a license server installed which is running out of licenses. I want to make sure that my machine does not take a seat if I ever happen to start IntelliJ.

I dont see remove Icon anywhere:
[image]

Moderator note: please don't suggest how to crack the software or remove trial period limitation.

Comment: Just for those who come across this question in the future, you are now able to remove a license by going to `Help -> Register` then clicking `Remove License...` in the bottom-left of the dialog box

Comment: @Pranav A. - I dont see any option to `Remove License' in Ultimate 2019.1 version?

Comment: @PAA its still there. you need to have a valid license in order to get the option to remove it (iirc)

Answer (score 68):

To remove the license key:

1. [Find](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108) the IntelliJ configuration directory
2. [Find](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23379538-How-to-find-the-license-file-or-information-used-by-the-IDE) the .key license file
3. Remove or rename the .key license file

In my case on a Windows 7 machine I could find this license key in `C:\Users\you\.IntelliJIdea13\config\idea13.key`

Comment: Any way to do that with 2016.X version?

Comment: To people having recent versions (not sure from where, but 2016.x seem to have it) in the help menu, there is a "register" dialog that let's you easily change or remove your license. no need for dirty hand removing of files...

Answer (score 60):

For Linux to reset current 30 days expiration license, you must run code:

```
rm ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2019.3/options/other.xml
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2019.3/eval/*
rm -rf .java/.userPrefs
```

Comment: A little explanation here (or, at least, a brief commentary) would improve this answer. (I came across it in the Low Quality Posts review queue.)

Comment: this works for 2020.2, for 30 days again :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Not necessary to delete userPrefs though

Answer (score 36):

For Windows : Using batch program.

Write this code in a text file and save it.

```
REM Delete eval folder with licence key and options.xml which contains a reference  to it
for %%I in ("WebStorm", "IntelliJ", "CLion", "Rider", "GoLand", "PhpStorm") do (
  for /d %%a in ("%USERPROFILE%\.%%I*") do (
    rd /s /q "%%a/config/eval"
    del /q "%%a\config\options\other.xml"
  )
)

REM Delete registry key and jetbrains folder (not sure if needet but however)
rmdir /s /q "%APPDATA%\JetBrains"
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft" /f
```

Now rename the file `fileName.txt` to `fileName.bat`

Close phpstorm if running. **Disconnect internet.** Then run the file. Open phpstorm again. If nothing goes wrong you will see the magic.

**worst case** : If phpstorm still shows "License Expired", at first uninstall and then apply the above technique.

Answer (score 23):

Not sure about older versions, but in 2016.2 removing the `.key` file(s) didn't work for me.

I'm using my JetBrains account and used the 'Remove License' button found at the bottom of the registration dialog. You can find this under the `Help` menu or from the startup dialog via `Configure -> Manage License...`.

Comment: This is the way to do it in recent versions

Answer (score 13):

in linux/ubuntu you can do, run following commands

```
cd ~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1
rm eval/PyCharm201.evaluation.key
sed -i '/evlsprt/d' options/other.xml
cd ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains
rm -rf pycharm*
```

Comment: It still works.
Today is April 2021. 
Ubuntu 18.04, Pycharm Pro 2021.

Comment: it work for all all intellij product i guess in ubuntu

Answer (score 9):

A slightly modified version for all jetbrains products

```
rm ~/.config/JetBrains/**/options/other.xml
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/**/eval/*
rm -rf .java/.userPrefs
```

one thing to mention is that if you use sudo on these commands it will use roots home directory and not your user directory. So either change permissions first or remove the ~/ from the first 2 commands and run from home directory with sudo, like this

```
cd ~
sudo rm .config/JetBrains/**/options/other.xml
sudo rm -rf .config/JetBrains/**/eval/*
sudo rm -rf .java/.userPrefs
```

Answer (score 7):

I think there are more solutions!

You can start the app, and here are 3 things you can do:

1. If the app shows for the first time the "import settings" dialog and then the "create/open a project" dialog, you can click on `Settings` > `Manage License...` > `Remove License`, and that removes for all Jetbrains products*.
2. If you open products like IntelliJ IDEA and have projects currently active (like the app open automatically the all IDE without prompt), then click on `File` > `Close Project`, and follow the first step.
3. Inside any app of IntelliJ, click on `Help` > `Register...` > `Remove license`.

***In case you have a license for a pack of products**. If not, you have to remove the license per product individually. Check the 3rd step.

Comment: I dont see ``Help > Register... > Remove license`` now in Ultimate 2019.1 version?

Comment: Check again! The option is still there. Checked on Ultimate 2019.1.3

Comment: Could you please share screen shot ?

Comment: Hey, if I do fresh install and that time I don't see remove license. Remove License gets available when I add some key (in my case its working key) and now remove license option is coming.

Answer (score 5):

For PHPStorm 2020.3.2 on ubuntu inorder to reset expiration license, you should run following commands:

```
sudo rm ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.3/options/other.xml 
sudo rm ~/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.3/eval/*          
sudo rm -rf .java/.userPrefs
```

Comment: for phpstorm you have the eval reset plugin

Comment: (didnt format correctly will post again as new answer) A slightly modified version for all jetbrains products

rm ~/.config/JetBrains/**/options/other.xml

rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/**/eval/*

rm -rf .java/.userPrefs

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu Linux

**reset trial**

```
shopt -s nocaseglob;
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/phpstorm*/eval;
rm -rf ~/.config/JetBrains/phpstorm*/options/other.xml;
rm -rf ~/.java/.userPrefs/jetbrains;
```

**autoskip lisence window on startup**

`sudo apt install wmctrl xautomation`

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1
# wait 30 seconds for window
while [ $x -le 150 ]
do
    if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "User Agreement" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then 
        wmctrl -va "User Agreement";
        sleep 0.2;
        xte 'key Tab';
        sleep 0.2;
        xte  'key Space';
        sleep 0.2;
        xte  'key Space';
        sleep 0.2;
    fi
    

    if test $(wmctrl -l | grep "License Activation" 2>&1 | wc -l) -eq 1; then 
        wmctrl -va "License Activation";
        sleep 0.1;
        xte 'keydown Shift_L';
        sleep 0.005;
        xte 'key Tab';
        sleep 0.05; # you need to adjust timing (in ms) if script doesn't work
        xte  'key Tab';
        sleep 0.05;
        xte  'key Tab';
        sleep 0.005;
        xte  'keyup Shift_L';
        sleep 0.05;
        xte 'key Right';
        sleep 0.025;
        xte 'key Return';
        break
    fi
    sleep 0.2;
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/k1paris/80b65e77342135ae594cf3f52b544900

Answer (score 4):

Easily find in **Menu bar**

```
   `Help` > `Register` > `Remove license`
```

Answer (score 2):

for mac

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/GoLand2020.2/options/
rm -rf other.xml
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/GoLand2020.2/eval/
rm -rf *
```

I couldn't find the file mentioned for ubuntu answers (.java/.userPrefs)

But it worked after running the above commands.

Answer (score 1):

#### For new versions of IntelliJ

Redirect to JetBrains configuration directory

```
cd ~/.config/JetBrains/
```

Check already installed JwtBrains tools

```
ls
```

It shows this list for me

- IntelliJIdea2021.1
- PyCharm2020.3
- PyCharm2021.1

My PyCharm has already activated and I have a `pycharm.key` file in `PyCharm2020.3` directory

I am just typing

```
cp ./PyCharm2020.3/pycharm.key ./IntelliJIdea2021.1/idea.key
```

Then when I trying to run my IntelliJ IDEA it works and doesn't want any activation key or login

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After I restarted the Intellij, I found that you can manage the license under the options menu.