# How do I remove my IntelliJ 2019.1 license?

Tags: intellij-idea

I went through [How do I remove my IntelliJ license?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584948/how-do-i-remove-my-intellij-license) and follow all the steps as mentioned here.

For `.IntelliJIdea2019.1` in **Windows 10**

- locate the folder `.IntelliJIdea2019.1`
- move the location `.IntelliJIdea2019.1\config\eval`
- remove the file `idea191.evaluation.key`

But just after couple of mins, I'm getting below error and it causing the IDE to close out.

How to solve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Try this, spend a few hours today with the same issue [answered in the main post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57236125/8877698) but maybe you already fixed it yourself(19 days ago)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue by buying a license for IntelliJ IDEA. If you need an extended evaluation, you can obtain one by emailing sales@jetbrains.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall intellij app from the system
2. Remove the entire folder .IntelliJIdea2019.1
3. Get rid of JavaSoft folder with all subfolders from the registry

If you want your intellij's back, restart the system and install version 2019.1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Goto bellow location
<kbd>windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> tyepe `%appdata%`  or

```
   C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains
```

and delete everything and restart the app will allow you to use evaluate again.